# nodejs - array of objects fetch info and add new object foreach object

Tags: node.js

i will try to explain my problem here and what i want to complete in this task:

```
const getPosts = async (req, res, next) => {
  let posts;
  try {
    posts = await Status.find({}).sort({ date: "desc" });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError(
      'backend_message1',
      500
    );
    return next(error);
  }

  return res.json({ posts: posts });
};
```

With this code i fetch all posts from my database and output looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 60b39c057a5db20314c69b37,
    creator: 609b176f4207251738e18aaa,
    body: 'test:d',
    date: 'Sun May 30 2021 16:07:01 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60b39b827a5db20314c69b36,
    creator: 609b176f4207251738e18aaa,
    body: 'tsx:d',
    date: 'Sun May 30 2021 16:04:50 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60b395ec7a5db20314c69b34,
    creator: 609b176f4207251738e18aaa,
    body: "dddddd",
    date: 'Sun May 30 2021 15:41:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
    __v: 0
  },
  {
    _id: 60b391ec7a5db20314c69b33,
    creator: 609b176f4207251738e18aaa,
    body: "lorem",
    date: 'Sun May 30 2021 15:23:56 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

And now as you see i have here creator id, but instead of using two fatches in frontend i got idea to fetch users info from backend and just ad object for each this object and just update it then map on frontend.. I still dont know is this a good idea to do all this in backend, but when i try to do it on front i cant do it successful because my response is to slow..

So thing that i want here is when i fetch posts i also want to fetch creator info and then update every object with that creator informations like name and image.. So finall result should be something like this:

```
[
...
{
    _id: 60b39c057a5db20314c69b37,
    creator: 609b176f4207251738e18aaa,
    body: 'test:d',
    date: 'Sun May 30 2021 16:07:01 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',
    creatorinfo: {
        username: Test Test,
        email: test@live.com,
        picture: somepictureimage.jpg
     }
    __v: 0
}
]
```

I hope I didn't complicate it too much with the question, all the best.
Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `array.map` and `Promise.all` to replace the `creator` id with the creator object. I don't have enough info to provide a copy-paste code solution, but this should lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes thanks for reply, but is it good to do this in backend or should i do this proccess on frontend?

Comment: You shouldn't let the frontend access the database directly unless there is security.

Comment: I didnt think like that, i also have api for userinfo for specific id so whats best solution to do this? In this example i want to fetch more things like posts then aurhorinfo than maybe comments etc.. But if i do fetch in map it take me too long to get user name like on open its show blank then after few seconds i got name..

Comment: Need some solution like in php where is WHILE like mysqli_fetch_array .. Any example for that i give code in first post..

Comment: I thought you were using node.js. Please modify your question with PHP code and make it clear that you want PHP.

Comment: Hello, sorry for missunderstanding.. Im using reactjs for my frontend and nodejs for my backend.. What I need currently is that I can do more fetches like fetch posts and then fetch author informations but i need them to display in same time on my frontend.. I just searching for correct way to do this and should it be on my frontend or backend.. Any examples?